# Regarding optimization for 'not a statment' in c?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization, logical-operators

While Learning compiler Optimisation, I write codes in `C` under `Linux` with `GCC` version `gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1)`
To understant `not a statement` (nop) in C. I written two codes first `y.c` second `x.c` and `generate their compiled assembly code` using `gcc -S` option.

Fist code **y.c**

```
desktop:~$ cat y.c
main()
{
int i=0;
}
desktop:~$ gcc -S y.c
desktop:~$
```

Second code **x.c**

```
desktop:~$ cat x.c
main()
{
int i=0;

/* Loops and if*/
while(0);
for(;0;);
if(0);

/* Arithmetic Operations */
i * i;
i / i;
i - i;
i + i;
i % i;
 +i;
 -i;

/* Comparison operators */
i == i;
i != i;
i < i;
i > i;
i >= i;
i <= i;

/* Bitwise Operations*/
i ^ i;
i | i;
i & i;
 ~i;
i << i;
i >> i;

/* Address Operatins*/ 
 &i;
 *(&i);
 (&i)[i];

/* Ternary conditional operation*/
 i? i : i;

/* Other Operations*/ 
 sizeof(i);
 (char)i;

/* Not-Logical Operation*/ 
 !i; 

/* Logical AND , OR Operators */ 
// i && i;  // Commented && operation 
// i || i;  // Commented || operation
}
desktop:~$ gcc -S x.c
```

**NOTICE**:  This time Last two lines in `x.c` are commented.
And as I was expecting. There is no difference in their generated assembly codes. I compared `x.s` and `y.s` using `diff` command.

```
desktop:~$ diff x.s y.s
1c1
<   .file   "x.c"
---
>   .file   "y.c"
desktop:~$
```

But When I uncomment last(or say add) two lines in `x.c`.

```
i && i;  
i || i;
```

Again compile x.c with -S option and compared with y.s.

```
desktop:~$ tail  x.c  
 sizeof(i);
 (char)i;

/* Not-Logical Operation*/ 
 !i; 

/* Logical AND , OR Operators */ 
i && i;  // unCommented && operation 
i || i;  // unCommented || operation
}
desktop:~$ gcc -S x.c
desktop:~$ diff x.s y.s
1c1
<     .file    "x.c"
---
>     .file    "y.c"
10,21d9
<     movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
<     testl    %eax, %eax
<     je    .L3
<     movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
<     testl    %eax, %eax
< .L3:
<     movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
<     testl    %eax, %eax
<     jne    .L8
<     movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
<     testl    %eax, %eax
< .L8:
desktop:~$
```

**Question**:
I just can not understand why expressions `i || i` and `i && i` are not equivalent to `'not a statement'`?

Why compiler transfer this two statements into executable( we can disassemble with `objdump` will get same code). What is special in this two expression. they do not includes `=` operation.

Does they change (set/reset) CPU flag-registers ? I guess no!

Even `/` division operation discarded that may cause an divided by zero fault.

**EDIT** : Added answer

There is nothing special in `i || i` and `i && i` expressions. Both are equivalent to 
NOT A STATEMENT. And can be removed by `GCC compiler`  with some extra effort.

To remove this:  `-o2` and `-o3` flags are useful:
Here is my Try!!

```
desktop:~$ gcc -o2 -S y.c 
desktop:~$ gcc -o2 -S x.c 
desktop:~$ diff x.s y.s -y
    .file   "x.c"                         |     .file   "y.c"
    .text                               .text
    .p2align 4,,15                        <
.globl main                         .globl main
    .type   main, @function                     .type   main, @function
main:                               main:
    pushl   %ebp                            pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp                      movl    %esp, %ebp
    popl    %ebp                          |     subl    $16, %esp
                                  >     movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
                                  >     leave
```

The extra lines in at RHS are because of misalignment between files.

I also like to add information that `JAVA` and `C#` compilers discard this expressions without any flags.

Comment: `I think compiler should discard last two expressions too!`, ** Not** ?

Comment: Ask it to optimise, and I expect it will remove them. Not sure why unoptimised it leaves them in, probably it would need to analyse the code a bit more than it does without optimising to be sure they have no side effects.

Comment: One important difference is that the C logical operators `&&` and `||` implement short-circuit boolean logic and this typically involves a flow of control. This is very different from a normal arithmetic or logical operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable optimizations using `-O2`, and you should see the extra code disappear.

Comment: `$ gcc -02 -S x.c`  results 
`gcc: unrecognized option '-02'`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan it's O ('Oh'), not 0 ('zero').

Comment: Thanks Alexey Feldgendler your post was useful and worked for me!