# The #define variable usage

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

I am working on a project written in C programming language. I got a code snippet as below

```
unsigned char value[10];
#define arr() (&value[0])
```

Why have they defined a "function"(`arr()`) kind of `#define`'d variable for an unsigned char array?

They are trying to use the variable like `arr()[1],arr()[2]` etc.,

1. Is `arr() + 2` equal to `value + 2`. I tried executing a small program, but theses two results gave me different answers. how is it possible. Because they are assigning the address of first array to `arr()`. Should these two not be the same?

Can anyone explain what is the significance of defining a variable as above?

Comment: That's not a function, that's a [macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html). And can you show the small program you used that gave you different answers? They should give the same.

Comment: I think it would take a psychic to know why they `#define`d `arr()` like that.

Comment: @Cornstalks its possible they wanted to decay the array to a pointer. However, that doesn't explain why they wanted a function-like macro

Comment: you could have used '#define arr() (value)' as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you *why* they've done it, but yes, `arr() + 2` and `value + 2` are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This line `#define arr() (&value[0])` means that whenever the preprocessor (which runs before the compiler) encounters `arr()` it replaces it in the file with `(&value[0])`.

So `arr()[1]` means `(&value[0])[1]`. `value[0]` is what's stored at the first index of value, `&` takes its address of it again... which is the same as value. So it should just be `value[1]` overall, unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

`arr()[i]` ==> `(&value[0])[i]` ==> `value[i]`

Also

`arr() + i`  ==> `(&value[0]) + i`  ==> `value + i`

So

`arr() + 2`  ==> `(&value[0]) + 2`  ==> `value + 2`

<sub>I can only guess that programmer writing this way to make coding uniform with other part of hist code like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095350/define-something-1-0)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> Is arr() + 2 equal to value + 2. I tried executing a small program,
>   but these two results gave me different answers. how is it possible.
>   Because they are assigning the address of first array to arr(). Should
>   these two not be the same?

Yes they are the same.

Try this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define arr() (&value[0])

int main(void)
{

unsigned char value[11] = "0123456789";
printf("arr()[2] = %c\n",  arr()[2] );
printf("arr()+ 2 = %c\n",*(arr() + 2) );
printf("value+ 2 = %c\n",*(value + 2) );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should write `value[11]`, as the string `"0123456789"` has actual length `11` including `\0`.