# What does typedef enum syntax like '1 << 0' mean?

Tags: objective-c, c, syntax, enums, typedef

I'm somewhat familiar with the typedef enum syntax of C and C++.  I'm now programming in Objective-C and came across the syntax in the following example.  I'm not sure if the syntax is Objective-C specific or not.  But, my question is in the following code snippet, what does syntax like `1 << 0` mean?

```
typedef enum {
   CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical = 1 << 0,
   CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical = 1 << 1,
   CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical = 1 << 2,
   CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical = 1 << 3
} CMAttitudeReferenceFrame;
```

Comment: Thanks Carl for the post.  Just an FYI, I did search before posting.  But I didn't know it was called bit shifting.

Comment: No problem, that's what we're here for. =)

Comment: You question answered here: [define SOMETHING `(1 << 0)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095350/define-something-1-0) and to understand `<<` operator  [vies this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708493/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-declaration/15708566#15708566)

Comment: I see that someone tagged my question as a duplicate.  I looked at the article titled Absolute Beginner's Guide to Bit Shifting, before I posted my question.  My question isn't a duplicate, because I specified my question is specific to Objective-C.  While I know Objective-C is derived from C, it's possible that Apple might have added some additional bit shifting capabilities to Objective-C.  Hence, I asked my question specific to Objective-C.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is common to the C-family of languages, and works identically in C, C++, and Objective-C.  Unlike Java, Pascal, and similar languages, a C enum is not limited to the values named for it; it actually is an integral type of a size that can represent all the named values, and one can set a variable of the enum type to an arithmetic expression in the enum members. Typically, one uses bit shifts to make the values powers of 2, and one uses bit-wise logical operations to combine values.

```
typedef enum {
   read    = 1 << 2,  // 4
   write   = 1 << 1,  // 2
   execute = 1 << 0   // 1
} permission;  // A miniature version of UNIX file-permission masks
```

Again, the bit-shift operations are all from C.

You can now write:

```
permission all = read | write | execute;
```

You could even include that line in the permission declaration itself:

```
typedef enum {
   read    = 1 << 2,  // 4
   write   = 1 << 1,  // 2
   execute = 1 << 0,  // 1
   all     = read | write | execute // 7
} permission;  // Version 2
```

How do you turn `execute` on for a file?

```
filePermission |= execute;
```

Note that this is dangerous:

```
filePermission += execute;
```

This will change something with value `all` to `8`, which makes no sense.

Comment: +1 By far the best answer.

Comment: Great answer.  Very clear and concise.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

`<<` is called the left shift operator.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#Bitwise_Left_Shift

Long story short `1 << 0 = 1`, `1 << 1 = 2`, `1 << 2 = 4` and `1 << 3 = 8`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `typedef` is representing a bit field value. `1 << n` is `1` shifted left `n` bits. So each `enum` item represents a different bit setting. That particular bit set or clear would indicate something being one of two states. `1` shifted left by zero bits is `1`.

If a datum is declared:

```
CMAttitudeReferenceFrame foo;
```

Then you can check any one of four independent states using the `enum` values, and `foo` is no bigger than an `int`. For example:

```
if ( foo & CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical ) {
    // Do something here if this state is set
}
```