# Understanding the increment operator in C

Tags: c, syntax, lvalue

Why is the following illegal in C?

```
y = (w + x)++;
```

According to my book, this is illegal, but I don't see why.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In `i++`, the *value* of `i` is changed.  After execution, `i`'s value is one plus its previous value.  You can't store a value in `w+x`, though, and so you can't do any of the following, which all (if they worked) would have more or less the same effect:

```
w+x = w+x+1;
w+x += 1;
(w+x)++;
```

Something that can be placed on the left hand side of an assignment is typically called an *lvalue* (*l* is for *left*).  The concise way of saying this is that `++` can only be applied to lvalues, and `w+x` isn't an lvalue.  You can read more about lvalues (and other kinds of values) in this question and its answers:

- [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/1281433)

Answer (score 8):

According to Dennis M. Ritchie's book: ["The C Programming Language"](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf):

> #### 2.8 Increment and Decrement Operators
>
> (page 44)
>
> The increment and decrement operators can only be applied to variables; an expression like `(i + j)++` is illegal. The operand must be a `modifiable lvalue` of arithmetic or pointer type.

Because an expression

```
i++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
i = i + 1;
```

So an expression like:

```
(i + j)++;
```

something like equivalent to:

```
(i + j) =  (i + j) + 1;  // meaning less
```

That looks meaning less, we can't modify expression.

**Related:** An interesting bug one may like to know about in gcc 4.4.5 is that expression `j = ++(i | i);` compiles that should produce l-value error. Read: [`j = ++(i | i);` and `j = ++(i & i);` should an error: lvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860189/j-i-i-and-j-i-i-should-an-error-lvalue)

Read about modifiable lvalue from (1) [Expression must be a modifiable lvalue error](http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=82120) and (2) msdn docs: [Lvalues and Rvalues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx)

Comment: It's good to cite sources (and this is good one), but I wish the book didn't say “variables,” though, because there are more lvalues than there are variables.  You can do, for instance, `a[i]++` and (*p)++.  It's not right to say "we can't modify [the value of] expression" though, since variables are also expressions, as are other lvalues.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Defiantly Nice example Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Note but `++(*p)++` this is lvalue error :) While `++*p++`  is  **NOT**

Comment: Sure, but that's a precedence issue.  What exactly is `++*p++` _doing_?  What's incremented?  What pointer is deferenced?  What's incremented afterward?  I'm not sure without testing, but I expect that since it compiles, it's doing (p = p+1), then doing `++(*p)`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor `++*p++` is equivalent  to `++*p;` `p++;` first value addressed by `p` is incremented then `p` itself incremented to make point to next location. Note parenthesized version of  `++*p++` is: `++(*(p++));`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Regardless of how it's parsed, it still drives home the point that the argument to the pre- and post-increment operators can be arbitrary lvalues, not just variables.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor The first link I given describes technically what is modifiable lvalue.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor As I had good discussion with you. I wanted to share a docs statement regarding your first comment. [read from here](http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=82120) "The assignment requires a unary-expression on the left side. A cast-expression is not part of a unary-expression. As mentioned above, you can use a unary-operator before the cast-expression to get a unary-expression, such as `'*'`."

Answer (score 5):

`y = x++` returns the value of the increment on the variable `x`.

`y = (x + z)++` fails because `(x + z)` is NOT a variable.

Answer (score 4):

It's illegal because `(w+x)` is not a legal left hand side value.

A **left hand side value** is a value that can be assigned to (I.E. a variable).

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science) for more details.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Post-increment requires an [l-value](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/lvalue.htm), which `w+x` is not.

Comment: I like to change it `post/prefix incremented and decrements` Also want to share a link: [Expression must be a modifiable lvalue error](http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=82120)

Answer (score 2):

It is illegal because `(x+y)` is not a variable.

Consider

`a++` is `a = a + 1`

`(x+y)++` is what? `(x+y) = (x+y) + 1`?

Answer (score 2):

Post inctrement and decrement requires `l-value` (say a variable which comes on left side). `w+x` is not a variable.  Incrementing `w+x` is like incrementig `3 + 4`, which is illegal.